# PrepareForSegue without functional

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a TableView with 8 sections. All section has 4 Row's. For each row there are a detail view controller.

I have now added a SearchBar in table view. The search works and the result is displayed to me in the search display controller.

But I can no longer go to the Details View. It is always shown me the same DetailsView.

What I have done wrong in the method "PrepareForSegue" and "didSelectRowAtIndexPath"?

Methode "prepareForSegue":

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"BrasilienSegue"]) {
    BrasilienViewController *BVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BVC.BrasilienLaenderLabel = [self.searchCountriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        BVC.BrasilienLaenderLabel = [self.listeDerNationen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"KroatienSegue"]) {
    KroatienViewController *KVC = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;

    if ([self.searchDisplayController isActive]) {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        KVC.kroatienLaenderLabel = [self.searchCountriesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        KVC.kroatienLaenderLabel = [self.listeDerNationen objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Methode "didSelectRowAtIndexPath":

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[self tableView: self.tableView  accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"BrasilienSegue" sender: self];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"KroatienSegue" sender: self];
}

}
```

Comment: You deselect the cell, so you couldn't do `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

Comment: I have modified the line "NSIndexPath *indexPath = nill;". unfortunately without success.

Comment: Try in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"BrasilienSegue" sender:@{@"IndexPath":indexPath}];` and in `prepareForSegue`: `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [sender objectForKey:@"IndexPath"];`

Comment: Thanks for you help. I changed the methods. Now crashes the TableView and the searchDisplayController when I press the Detail Disclosure Button.

Comment: What's the error message? Did you checked that the `indexPath` in `perpareForSegue` what the right one? Note, the crash may be because `VC.XxXLabel` as it names stands, is a `UILabel` and not an `NSString` as I supposed is store in yours arrays.

Comment: Thist is the error massage.

Comment: 2014-04-19 16:20:04.897 Info[5315:70b] (null)
2014-04-19 16:20:06.312 Info[5315:70b] -[GruppenTableViewController objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b24e500
2014-04-19 16:20:06.314 Info[5315:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GruppenTableViewController objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b24e500'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: VC.XXXLabel is a label in the details view controller.

Comment: Could you try moving the line `[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];` from `didSelect...` to the end of each of if statements in `prepareForSegue...`??

Comment: Sorry, but that move has unfortunately brought nothing. I have the code checked with the debugger. In the method "prepareForSegue" in line "NSIndexPath * indexPath = [sender objectForKey: @" indexPath "];" crashes the TableView. But what is wrong with the objectForKey?

Comment: Hello, does anyone have another idea.